# How to toggle between different checkboxses Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have four check boxes every click on a check box initiates a different function. One one check box is selected all other should be deselected. I have the following code but the problem is that I cannot toggle between check without first manually removing the check mark and then selecting the other one. 
My code:

```
  $scope.checkbox = function(key){
        if($scope.checkbox1 === true){
          $scope.checkbox2 = false
          $scope.checkbox3 = false
          $scope.checkbox4 = false
          $scope.checkboxValue = 'checkbox one was clicked'
          callfunctionOne()
        } else if($scope.checkbox2 === true){
           $scope.checkbox1 = false
          $scope.checkbox3 = false
          $scope.checkbox4 = false
          $scope.checkboxValue = 'checkbox two was clicked'
          callfunctiontwo()
        } else if($scope.checkbox3 === true){
           $scope.checkbox1 = false
          $scope.checkbox2 = false
          $scope.checkbox4 = false
          $scope.checkboxValue = 'checkbox three was clicked'
          callfunctionthree()
        } else if($scope.checkbox4 === true){
           $scope.checkbox1 = false
          $scope.checkbox2 = false
          $scope.checkbox3 = false
          $scope.checkboxValue = 'checkbox Four was clicked'

       callfunctionFour()
        } 

        }
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/08m2bG?p=preview)**

Comment: for that you can use radio button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $scope.checkbox = function(key){
    $scope.checkbox1 = false
    $scope.checkbox2 = false
    $scope.checkbox3 = false
    $scope.checkbox4 = false
    $scope[key] = true;
    $scope.checkboxValue = 'checkbox '+key+' was clicked'
 }
```

You should consider using radio buttons but this code allows you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is really helpful but if I want to call a seprate function each time one condition is true how can I do that?

Comment: @lmi I would change the `ng-change` for the function you want and just call `$scope.checkbox(key)` inside it or do a `switch` inside the `$scope.checkbox` function. It's really up to you but if you have any issues just update the plunker

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach for your code:

1. Use one common variable for `ng-model` for all checkboxes,
2. and then use `ng-true-value` to identify which checkbox was selected

**Example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GaU1GUlKlXrU3RVzsNyR?p=preview)**

```
<!-- AngularJS Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.setValues = function(){
    $scope.checkbox1 = false;
    $scope.checkbox2 = false;
    $scope.checkbox3 = false;
    $scope.checkbox4 = false;

    $scope['checkbox'+tempVariable] = true;
  };
});
</script>

<!-- HTML Code -->
<label class="label--checkbox " id="checkbox1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="tempVariable" ng-click="setValues()" ng-true-value="1">
  <span class="checkboxLabelText">
    Checkbox 1 : {{checkbox1}}
  </span>
</label>

<label class="label--checkbox" id="checkbox2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="tempVariable" ng-click="setValues()" ng-true-value="2">
  <span class="checkboxLabelText">
    Checkbox 2 : {{checkbox2}}
  </span>
</label>

<label class="label--checkbox" id="checkbox3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="tempVariable" ng-click="setValues()" ng-true-value="3">
  <span class="checkboxLabelText">
    Checkbox 3 : {{checkbox3}}
  </span>
</label>

<label class="label--checkbox" id="checkbox4">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" ng-model="tempVariable" ng-click="setValues()" ng-true-value="4">
  <span class="checkboxLabelText">
    Checkbox 4 : {{checkbox4}}
  </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you got the required answer but here's an nice custom directive  for [Multi checkbox](https://ngcoderscope.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/multi-checkbox-directive/) which handles most of the cases.

Comment: Great! Thanks you are right I already got the answer but this will be very helpful in the future